# Start and Stop Wildfly server from Main() Class

Tags: java, wildfly, program-entry-point

Currently I´m trying to start and stop the Wildfly Server from my Main() Class.
Is there a way to do this?

I guess I can use this for starting the Wildfly Server:

```
   String path = "/myPath/standalone.bat";  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new
    String[] { "cmd.exe", "/c", path } );
```

But how can I stop the server / kill the same process (JAVA Runtime for the server)?
Thank you for any help

Answer (score 1):

You can perform the shutdown of the server using CLI command.

```
$JBOSS_HOME/bin/jboss-cli.sh --connect --controller=<host>:<port> -c --command=:shutdown
```

For more details, see https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/Suspend,+Resume+and+Graceful+shutdown.

Though, I wonder why you want to perform such a task from a java class.

Comment: I saw this already but how can I implement this directly in the main method from java?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`ServerHelper.shutdownStandalone()`](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/wildfly/plugin/core/ServerHelper.java#L309-L348) from the [WildFly Plugin Core project](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly-maven-plugin/tree/master/core). Or you could just use the `shutdown` operation.